# Event Proposal: The Anime.SE Community Holiday Gift Exchange

Tags: discussion, community-events

I'm here to gauge interest in doing an Anime and Manga Stack Exchange gift exchange for the month of December. The specifics are still in the air but your question, comments, and suggestions are welcome.

The idea is as follows:

- You are pseudo-randomly given a number and matched up with another person, who will send you a present. You will only send that address to that one person and no one else. I'll try to pair people close to one another, if possible. However it is likely that most people will be shipping internationally.
- The gift can be physical or digital. The suggested value of the gift should be ~$20 USD or equivalent (once you factor in the cost of living in your area; TODO: Find some sort of stable product to use for value reference). You may exceed the recommend amount, but know that your gesture might or might not be reciprocated. You can avoid hassles and high cost/hassle of shipping by sending your gift digitally.
- The gift should be anime or manga related, but this is more of a soft requirement.
- Gifts should arrive by the beginning of January at the latest, but ideally before Christmas/Hanukkah/Kwanzaa/etc holiday. International post will be given more leeway.
- Eligibility will probably be given to users who have been here for at least 1 month (by December) and have at least 50 rep OR have accumulated at least 200 rep. Whichever criteria is fulfilled first.
- Giftees may post or send their preference in terms of gifts to the Gifter, but it is up to the Gifter to decide what to send.
- Gifters do not need to disclose what they are sending the giftee, unless their country's customs enforcement requires them to. Marking your gifts as "gifts" may help you or your giftee avoid certain taxes.
- Please don't send any inappropriate or slanderous items that the giftee might not enjoy.
- Participation is on an opt-in basis (probably via Google Forms). This is purely a community event and is by no way associated or endorsed by the site, Stack Exchange, or it's operators. We can't be responsible for damaged, lost packages, etc. But if you never got you package by a certain date, we can at least try to match you up with someone who's willing to re-gift.

If this is popular enough, we might continue this in the future and possibly make a web app to handle matching.

Please leave your questions, comments, and/or suggestions in this thread. They are always welcomed.

Comment: If you want to participate but cannot due to one reason or another, let us know why and we'll see if we can accommodate or figure out a better idea.

Comment: How far in advance will the match ups be done?

Comment: The event has been launched, [here](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/1131/49) are all the details.

Answer (score 4):

One worry I'd have is that I feel 200 rep is too low a barrier to entry. By all means I want more participants - but I also want to have my gift reciprocated, and it might just me being sceptical but I feel newer users would be less likely to do so

Maybe you could have two tiers 800+ & 200+, or something.

Or if I'm the only one who feels like this, you could just change mine if I'm matched with someone very new. Or maybe people could pick who to gift?

Another question I have is:  Will giftees know who their gifters are before receiving their present? You mentioned sending preferences to gifters so this is what brought this question up in my mind. Maybe it could be mentioned by participants with their entry post (if done on meta)

Comment: I'd rather only the gifter know the giftee's addresses (provided by the giftee). So for simplicity/security purposes it will not be a "secret Santa" type of event (if it's well received, it can be in the future).